# CMake and GCOV on Mac OS X with Clang compiler, generating gcno but not gcna

Tags: xcode, macos, cmake, gcov

I'm working on a C project and using CMake. I've been trying to get coverage testing working with GCOV and am just about there.

This is what I have figured out so far:

```
-use clang for c compiler. "gcc" on the latest Xcode does nothing with -fprofile-arcs and -ftest-coverage
-add -fprofile-arcs and -ftest-coverage to c debug flags
-set cmake build type to Debug
-run cmake to build makefile
-double check that gcno files are created for each source file compiled (they are).
```

This is where i'm stuck now. I run one of my unit tests and I don't get any .gcna files created.

The strange thing is that when I use CMake to generate an Xcode project, and turn on "Generate Test Coverage Files" and "Instrument Program Flow", I get both gcno and gcna files.

I've verified when running make with VERBOSE=1 that the correct compiler and linker flags are being used.

I've also looked in Xcode to see if there's any other libraries or special switches that Xcode is using that isn't being used in the makefile - I don't see anything other than -fprofile-arcs and -ftest-coverage.

Anyone else experienced this?

I'd love to be able to get the gcna files generating so I don't have to go into Xcode for everything.

Comment: figured it out. the gcna files were being put in non-obvious places within cmake cache dirs.

Comment: And how exactly did you fix it?